# As websocket connections increase app starts to hang

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.0

Just getting invited to look at an issue in a third party application where the behavior is as more clients connect (using web socket) app hangs after a certain connections. I am trying to get more info and better access to the codebase but below is what I have right now which looks like a standard code flow. Any gottachs to keep in mind when play, akka, web sockets are in the mix? Will post more info as it becomes available.

Controller has

```
def service = WebSocket.async[JsValue] { request =>
       Service.createConnection
 }
```

Service.createConnection looks as

```
def createConnection: Future[(Iteratee[JsValue, _], Enumerator[JsValue])] = {

val serviceActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[ServiceActor])

val socket_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString

val (enumerator, mChannel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]

    (serviceActor ? Connect(socket_id, mChannel)).map{
    ...........
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the number of connections after which problems begin?

Comment: I was told they don't have a consistent numbers after which hangs since they have observed it has hung after 18-20 and other times 8-10. I am trying to get more codebase access as early as they can grant.

Comment: I would avoid the `ask` pattern with `tell` pattern using a dummy actor. Something along the lines of: 

val promise = AkkaPromise[A]()(executionContext)

val dummyActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new AkkaActor {
def receive = {
 case result: MyResponse => promise.complete(result)
}

serviceActor.tell(Connect(socket_id, mChannel), dummyActorRef)


Note that I am using Akka actors, but it should mostly be similar.

Comment: First thing would be not a codebase, but checking what is going on with hardware (CPU, network, IO, RAM). And if all is definitely clear there, move to codebase.
Would you be kind to provide those details first?